# VBA excel macro - add rows above button

Tags: excel, vba

in my Sheet I'm trying to create VBA code which will allow me to:
1)add specific (constant) number of rows above clicked button
2)format them in a proper way

What I know is every object (shape) stores value of TopLeftCell which from where I can get row number.
I can simply add rows(s) above or belowe specific row in my Sheet

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(21).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

I would like to create where function addNewRows2 is unviersal for any button in the ActiveSheet - it gets the position of button(the row number) and adds row(s) above it

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
addNewRows2
End Sub

Function addNewRows2()
   Application.ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Insert 
End Function
```

Comment: What is your question / what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

In Class module `cButton` put the following lines

```
Public WithEvents MyButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub MyButton_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Rows(MyButton.TopLeftCell.Row).Insert
End Sub
```

Then in standard module put the code

```
Dim TheCommandButtons() As New cButton

Sub Activate_ActiveX_CommandButtons()
    Dim shp As Shape, iButtonCount As Long
    ReDim TheCommandButtons(1 To 1)
    iButtonCount = 0
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.OLEFormat.Object.OLEType = xlOLEControl Then
            iButtonCount = iButtonCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve TheCommandButtons(1 To iButtonCount)
            Set TheCommandButtons(iButtonCount).MyButton = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Now run the code `Activate_ActiveX_CommandButtons`, after that you can use any command button to do the task of inserting a row above the button.